# Removing case sensitivity

Tags: c#

My program has a search and update function. But it will only find a match if the user types in Jane Doe not jane doe. ATM my programs retrieving user input, converting into char array and changing the first letter of each word but this doesn't seem to work either. This is the code I'm using..

Any help on how to go about this would be great and why my method of conversion isn't working :)

Comment: Not migrating to a more appropriate site as this question seems to be too basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, strings have a number of comparison functions, such as the `Equals` function, that have case insensitive overloads.

Another possibility you might look into, if the array you're searching in is sorted, is the `Array.BinarySearch<string>` function.

Comment: Are you able to explain why my method of comparison isn't working?

Comment: You didn't specify your method of comparison. Can you post the code? And the real code this time?

Comment: Edited my post to include my if compare method

Comment: The inserting into array code segment is in a different method etc

Comment: You're using `==` in there. But like I said, you should use `Equals`. Specifically the one with the StringComparison parameter.

Comment: I've never used that before...    if (contPeople[i].name equals userContChange)?

Comment: It's a function. See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx). `if (contPeople[i].name.Equals(userContChange, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`